# Double Quotes In Command Line And Blueprism

Tags: command-line, blueprism

I am trying to use Nitro PDF reader via the command line from Blueprism.
Information here: https://kb.gonitro.com/knowledgebase/#/search/command/000004309

"Combine PDF Files

Nitro Pro: NitroPDF.exe /m  
E.g.: C:\Program Files\Nitro\Pro\12>NitroPDF.exe /m C:\Users\amanenti\Desktop\test.pdf C:\Users\amanenti\Desktop\test2.pdf

You can also insert the “/INS=before|after” switch.
Eg.:   NitroPDF.exe /INS=before  
Eg2.: NitroPDF.exe /INS=after  "

This is working for me when my filepath has no space. eg "C:\Users\mcandrewe\Desktop\Test.pdf"

However, it does not work when the path has spaces.

Argument

```
"/m" & Chr(34) & "T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112233 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf" & Chr(34) & "T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112234 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf"
```

Error:The Creation Process encountered an error. (Even though this should combine not create)

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit more of how exactly you're running this command through Blue Prism? Which object are you leveraging? Can you share the configuration for the action itself?

Comment: I am using Utility - Environment Run Process Until Ended. In Application I have "NitroPDF.exe", and my argument is "/m" & Chr(34) & "T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112233 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf" & Chr(34) & "T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112234 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For file paths containing whitespace, you need to enclose your path in double quotes (`"`). As you've discovered, since they're *also* used to delineate strings in Blue Prism expressions, you can't just use them straight away.

Blue Prism follows [VB.NET-style escape sequences](https://forums.asp.net/t/1053221.aspx?how+to+insert+double+quotes+to+a+string). With this knowledge, you can double-*double* quote where you'd like to use a double quote character within a string. Your argument for the `Utility - Environment` VBO's `Run Process` action would then look something like:

```
"/m ""T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112233 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf"" ""T:\Team Shares\Blue Prism\Shared Files\Customer\Member Requests\Member Downloads\2020\04\01\Post\123456789\112234 EOB 28_05_2018.pdf"""
```

It will look slightly different with the concatenation if you're attempting to pass paths from Data Items, however. The quotes tend to get a bit unwieldy, but are still usable:

```
"/m """ & [File Path 1] & """ """ & [File Path 2] & """"
```